# How to fix missing package for MYSQL 8.0 on CENTOS 7

Tags: centos, package, centos7, rpm

**Summary**
I try to install MYSQL community edition 8.0 on my Amazon Linux server

**Command i have done so far**

cd /home/ec2-user 
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-8.0.16-2.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar 
tar -xvf mysql-8.0.16-2.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar 
rpm -ivh mysql-community-server-8.0.16-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

**I get the following error :**
error: Failed dependencies:
        libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) is needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.16-2.el7.x86_64
        systemd is needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.16-2.el7.x86_64

**What i tried by now**
The library libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) is included in cyrus-sasl-lib
I tried to install it but still the same result
Here is the command i tried : sudo yum install cyrus-sasl-lib

**Operating System**
Linux ip-172-31-86-163 4.14.146-93.123.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 24 00:45:23 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Expected Result :
Success

Error Message i have :
Failed dependencies:
        libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) is needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.16-2.el7.x86_64

Comment: Why don't you use `yum` ? try `yum install mysql`.

Comment: When i do yum install mysql it install mysql 5.5  and i want 8.0. Is there a way to change this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
yum install /path/to/mysql-8...rpm
```

then `yum` will try to find the dependencies you need. If some dependencies cannot be found, you can try downloading them yourself, or enabling repositories. But be careful since you are trying to install recent software on an old os... I don't know if amazon has **centos8** machines already, otherwise that would probably help you out :)

Comment: still not working it still say need dependency, i am kinda new with linux. I also tryed this sudo yum install mysql-community-server
Still say that i need dependency ( the same 2 as my example ) So i need another OS ?

Comment: installation of `cyrus-sasl-lib` should have solved the problem. on my machine: `rpm -q cyrus-sasl-lib --provides` gives: `libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)` , which is the dependency you need.

Comment: Yes, this is what i have done in my example. When i try to install it i have this message : Package cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.16.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version  ..... but still the libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) is not installed. I dont see it in my lib64 folder this is very strange. I tryed with that command : sudo yum install cyrus-sasl-lib

Comment: did you try `rpm -q cyrus-sasl-lib --provides` ? What is the output?

Comment: Here is the result ec2-user:~/environment (master) $ rpm -q cyrus-sasl-lib --provides
cyrus-sasl-lib = 2.1.23-13.16.amzn1
cyrus-sasl-lib(x86-64) = 2.1.23-13.16.amzn1
libanonymous.so.2()(64bit)
libsasl2.so.2()(64bit)
libsasldb.so.2()(64bit)

Comment: ok, seems like you have an older version of `cyrus-sasl-lib` installed which provides `libsasl2.so.2` and not `libsasl2.so.3`. You'll have to get your hands on a more recent version. Trouble is you probably have other packages depending on your libsasl. So I'll reiterate my recommendation to get a more recent OS.

Comment: Thanks for your advice i will check what i can do but i seems to be limited with os since i am on Amazone AWS cloud9 developpement system and i cannot chose the OS behind it. Its bad because i need at least MYSQL 5.7 and ... 5.7 also need that library. Im stuck with old mysql 5.5 and it's not the best for Laravel framework